# Is it possible to execute an executable with authenticated SMB?

Tags: windows, windows-permissions, smb

Assume the following:

- An attacker has access to a remote Windows share on a remote host.
- Attacker manages to bruteforce a local Windows account on the host and can login to it via SMB.
- Attacker can write files via SMB.
- Victim is fully patched and attacker does not have any zero days.
- Victim is not a member of a domain controller, it is just a share with local Windows authen.

Can the attacker force the Windows computer to run an executable? If so, how?

Comment: If it's an admin account you can use psexec

Comment: Testing on my home network and it's failing "Access is denied." Pretty sure it's an admin account. Is it due to UAC?

Comment: Perhaps. This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16735900/psexec-and-uac-issue

Comment: Old question, but you could look into using the IPC$ share to communicate with named pipes, and do something like execute WMIC, modify the registry, or create a scheduled task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While psexec or wmiexec (Linux python equivalent) will work, the latest Windows updates do not work with the default installation.

This is because the ADMIN$ and C$ shares are not accessible without explicit registry configuration.